# Warehouse management recurring billing Database Design and Logic

Tags: sql, database, inventory, recurring-billing

I'm building an application for warehouse management and billing.  The storage is all pallets, so that is very simple, one pallet = $X per month.  But I'm struggling to think through the best Database design for keeping track of what needs billed when. A pallet could sit for a day a month a year etc...  They come and go at seemingly random intervals. One Customer may have over 1000 pallets that have all arrived at different times.
How can I best structure the database and logic to keep track of what has been billed, and what is due to be billed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Table 1:** Pallets (PalletID(PKey), Cost per month)

**Table 2:** Holdings (HoldingID(PKey), Customer ID, CustomerName, PalletsID, StartDate, ReturnDate )

You need a Java/.net based UI to pull data from these two tables, where by referring Pallets table, you can calculate amount as below

1. Customer X:
2. Start Date: XXXX:XX:XX
3. Return Date: XXXX:XX:XX
4. Get Count of months between these two dates.

**5. Billing amount will be count*Cost of Pallet**

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Some more specific questions.  lets say a pallet arrives july 15, and leaves on Aug 20.  That is 2 billing cycles.  I need to somehow mark it as shipped, but it still needs to be billed for the extra month, then of course not billed the following month.  How would I manage this?

Comment: You will have two dates 2016:07:15 and 2016:08:20. Using many inbuilt methods, you can calculate number of distinct months between these 2 dates. and simply noOfMonths*cost of Pallets

Comment: Good answer. Some tips… [Standard date format](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) uses hyphens rather than colons, YYYY-MM-DD such as 2016-01-23. Use `java.time.LocalDate` class to represent the dates if you have only one location and don't care about time zones (for any given moment the date varies by time zone).